# I changed permission of SQL Server Reporting Services through SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2012

Now I can't access Reporting Services through SSMS. I can't even connect to Reporting Services now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, see if the SSRS service is even running.

But if it's mainly a security thing, run a browser on the server as an administrator, and give your regular user some level of access again.